# Traffic incident and data in Bing Map Silverlight control

Tags: c#, silverlight

I am using bing map Silverlight 4 control and using virtual earth services for geocoding and reverse geocoding, now I need traffic incidents, and traffic data on map; these service are available in ajax control

How can I use this functionality in Silverlight control? 
Or is there any way to Populate map control(traffic data) by JSON or XML data?

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that you have seen this article about [Integrating Real-time Traffic Information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa907680.aspx) in Bing Maps AJAX Control 6.3. Silverlight and AJAX are complement to each other which means that you can consume AJAX control in Silverlight and vice-versa. [This slideshare is discussion this topic](http://www.slideshare.net/goodfriday/developing-aspnet-ajax-controls-with-silverlight). Hopefully it will help.

Comment: @husnain Check this link as well http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2010/04/12/silverlight-4-ria-services-ready-for-business-ajax-endpoint.aspx